# Alertas en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una duda, quisiera saber si en laravel puedo mostrar una alerta luego de hacer un redirect().
He mostrado alertas o notificaciones simplemente cuanto el return es seguido de un view("nombre_del_documento") y agregando el metodo ->whit("message", "tipodealerta");

Pero luego del redirect me dice que el metodo whit no es permitido.

```
//Esto es el metodo que si funciona
return view(index)->whit('message', 'store');

//Este es la forma que quiero utilizar
return redirect('/home')->whit('message', 'store');
```

Gracias por la ayuda de ante mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza este método para mostrar mensajes, agrega esto a la parte del controlador:

```
\Session::flash('message', 'store');
```

Y esto en la vista:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
   {!! Session::get('message') !!}
@endif
```